# Python Code after np.require(arr, dtype=np.float) is ignored?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I have some machine learning code that I want to get running.
My problem lies in the preprocessing part of it. At some point each sequence in the (time-series) dataset is exported into a pickle file.
For this an array with the sequence is reshaped and then np.require is used to ensure the datatype.

```
try:
    # checking if annotations are consistent
    data_x = normalize(data_x)
    if np.sum(data_y == labels[:, 0]) == data_y.shape[0]:

        # Sliding window approach
        print("Starting sliding window")
        X, y, y_all = opp_sliding_window(data_x, labels.astype(int),
                                            sliding_window_length,
                                            sliding_window_step, label_pos_end = False)
        print("Windows are extracted")

        # Statistics
        hist_classes = np.bincount(y[:, 0], minlength=NUM_CLASSES)
        hist_classes_all += hist_classes
        print("Number of seq per class {}".format(hist_classes_all))                
        for f in range(X.shape[0]):
            try:

                sys.stdout.write('\r' + 'Creating sequence file '
                                        'number {} with id {}'.format(f, counter_seq))
                sys.stdout.flush()
                # print "Creating sequence file number {} with id {}".format(f, counter_seq)
                seq = np.reshape(X[f], newshape = (1, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))                                    
                seq = np.require(seq, dtype=np.float)
                
                # Storing the sequences
                obj = {"data": seq, "label": y[f], "labels": y_all[f],
                        "identity": labels_persons[P]}
                f = open(os.path.join(data_dir, 'seq_{0:06}.pkl'.format(counter_seq)), 'wb')
                pickle.dump(obj, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
                f.close()

                counter_seq += 1
            except:
                raise('\nError adding the seq')

        print("\nCorrect data extraction from {}".format(FOLDER_PATH + file_name_norm))
        
        del data
        del data_x
        del data_y
        del X
        del labels
        del class_labels

    else:
        print("\nNot consisting annotation in  {}".format(file_name_norm))
        continue

except:
    print("\n In generating data, No file {}".format(FOLDER_PATH + file_name_norm))
```

The code after the `seq = np.require(seq, dtype=np.float)` is not executed and the print in the last except-block is executed. I tested this by printing something before and after that line. Nothing after was ever printed, right before it was printed.

If I comment out the np.require line everything seems to be working and the code is running through. Though the datatype of the array might not be right. That's why I kind of need to find out what is happening here and why it doesn't work.

Comment: it's really unclear what your question is. But for starters, **dont' wrap your code in a giant `try - except: pass` block**. This is absolutely not how you should be using exception handling. try-excepts should wrap the minimum amount of code possible, and should try to catch as specific exception as possible. bare except clauses are almost always bad. Remove that, and see what errors actually occur

Comment: It is sadly not my code, but the code I need to get running . I'll try doing that though.

Comment: And thank you, just deleting the outer try-except block seemed to solve the problem. I got an error about np.float not existing anymore and how I should just use float instead. Thank you very much!

Comment: If the question no longer holds, please delete it now.